# what is the difference between observer and subscriber in RXJS?

Tags: rxjs, observable, observers, subscriber

What is the difference between observer and subscriber in RXJS?

See the code below

```
// subscriber being used
const observable = new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next(1);
  subscriber.next(2);
})

// observer being used
const observable = new Observable(observer => {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.next(2);
})
```

What is the difference between observer and subscriber in the context above?

Comment: Please, take a look at your code one more time. I think you will realise that there is no difference between two variants in your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the same. In this case, `subscriber` or `observer` is just the name given to the function parameter. You could call it `anythingYouWant` and it would function the same:

```
const observable = new Observable(anythingYouWant => {
  anythingYouWant.next(1);
  anythingYouWant.next(2);
})
```

Comment: LOL sometimes you just need someone to point the obvious to you. Thank you.

Comment: No problem - RxJs terminology can be confusing sometimes :)